# how to find scheme part of requested URL in HTTP Request Handler

Tags: python, web-services, http, python-2.7, http-headers

I am using BaseHTTPRequestHandler class to handle HTTP requests in python. At one point i need the scheme of the requested URL.

i.e if requested url is http://abc.com then i need "http" but if requested url is https://def.com in need "def".

I have tried following things

1. Exploring the headers. As part of host header i am getting every thing, but scheme part of the URL.
2. looking at the output of path.string(). it is giving me relative URL path
3. looking at the output of address_string() (output i am getting is localhost.localdomain)

How can i get the scheme part??

Comment: Please enlighten me, what is the scheme of a URL.

Comment: I just read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme.  If i understand correctly https and http are schemes.  Are you indicating that when you do your check from a script that was launched via https, the scheme is obscured from your code?

Comment: yes this is exactly what i mean. Like if i am trying to send a request at http://abc.com , i am only getting "abc.com" in host header